# MapRequestPayload nested DTOs

Tags: php, json, symfony

I want to parse JSON Requests into nested DTOs with MapRequestPayload. The goal is to have the data into the DTOs validated.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "locale": "ger",
        "validateOnly": false
    },
    "content": {
        "firstName": "firstName",
        "lastName": "lastName",
        "displayMode": "system",
        "favoriteMandates": [
            {
                "mandateId": "{{mandateId}}",
                "position": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

"meta" always contains the same set of data, while content varies depending on endpoint.

**Update:** I've talked with a college about this and he wanted me to look into the second approach. So I rephrased everything below.

```
final class UpdateUserSettingsController {
    #[Route(
        path: '/api/v1/user/settings',
        methods: [HttpUpdate::REQUEST]
    )]
public function execute(
        #[MapRequestPayload(acceptFormat: 'json')]
        JsonRequest $request
    ): JsonResponse
    {
            $settingsDTO = new UpdateUserSettingsDto(...$request->content);
            //... do something
     }
}
```

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
final class JsonRequest
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Assert\Valid]
        public MetaWithAttributes    $meta,
        #[Assert\Type('array')]
        public array                 $content,
    )
    {}
}
```

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use CustomConstrains;

final readonly class UpdateUserSettingsDto
{
    public Name $name;
    public FavoriteMandatesCollection $favoriteMandates;

    public function __construct(
        string $firstName,
        string $lastName,
        #[Assert\IsArray] array $favoriteMandates,
        #[CustomConstrains\IsEnumValue(DisplayModeEnum::class)] string $displayMode,
    ) {
        $this->name = Name::fromStrings($firstName, $lastName);
        $this->favoriteMandates = FavoriteMandatesCollection::fromInputArray($favoriteMandates);
        $this->displayMode = DisplayModeEnum::fromString($displayMode);

    }
}
```

My problem now is that I need to tell Symfony somehow that the Attributes need to be checked (therefore somehow using the Validator?).

If someone got a different/better approach for solving this, without the need of a request-class and dto-class per endpoint, I'm happy to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add annotations (`@var array<Contact>` or `@var Contact[]`) to the array so that the mapper understands which class to use for object mapping and can apply the validator.

```
public function __construct(
    #[Assert\Type('countable')]
    #[Assert\All(new Assert\Type(type: Contact::class))]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    /** @var array<Contact> */
    public array          $contacts = [],
) {}
```

My example with payload:

```
"contacts": [
    {
      "title": "",
      "text": "",
      "href": "",
      "icon": "",
      "sortOrder": 0
    },
    {
      "title": "string",
      "text": "string",
      "href": "string",
      "icon": "string",
      "sortOrder": 0
    }
  ],
```

Output:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "contacts[0].title": "This value should not be blank.",
    "contacts[0].text": "This value should not be blank."
  }
}
```